# Is it possible to use AirDrop and Sidecar with a mac on a VPN?

Tags: vpn, airdrop, sidecar

I need to use a VPN on my mac from time to time. While I'm doing so, it interferes with  the ability to use AirDrop and Sidecar. My VPN has the ability to whitelist certain apps, so is there a collection of 'apps' that AirPlay and/or Sidecar uses?

I think Sidecar doesn't work with a wired connection when the VPN is on. I've tried whitelisting e.g. Finder but that's not enough, I'm not sure what else could be useful.

Comment: I use VPN and Sidecar, but it’s a split tunneling VPN. Maybe if we knew your VPN specifics, we could male suggestions.

Comment: @not2savvy, my VPN (ExpressVPN, run as an app on the mac) has a split tunneling feature, but its GUI based and requires me to select an app to whitelist/blacklist.

Comment: (BTW I have asked their support team but theres no live chat due to virus, will self answer if I get a working solution from them)

Comment: This seems not a conventional split tunneling, so I'm afraid I can't help without knowing details about the app.

Comment: @not2savvy I'm not getting a response from their support, could you sketch what you do to get your split tunneling working? I will attempt to adapt it to the tools I have

Comment: I use IPSecuritas which sets up the split tunneling for me. I know it can be set up manually specifying network routes but I haven’t done it myself. Maybe this helps you: https://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard

Comment: You could use Duet instead of Sidecar, that way you‘d have an app to whitelist?

Comment: @not2savvy thats a great idea actually I might try that in a couple of days when I give up again, thanks

Comment: Are you using the built-in VPN support or using a third party client?

Answer (score 1):

VPN can be set up to be compatible with both sidecar and airdrop.

The process of installing some VPN also can and will break these both if desired or they are targeted for blocking. The details matter of the network setup since macOS can have multiple networks assigned to one physical interface and software like VPN and admin control over networking can also block these transmissions.

Answer (score 0):

(This solved my similar issue with Airdrop, not tested Sidecar yet.)

I do not have VPN at router but on individual devices, so VPN broke my iCloud copy/paste and airdrop. It may be because they were not "sharing" the same wifi network anymore, as in, they had two different data tunnels, and the only solution I found was to deploy VPN at router or to turn off VPN.

I dig Mullvad VPN Mac app preferences, and found that there is an option to enable "Local network sharing" that allows local network access to connected devices. I turned it on and voila, I had my airdrop back. I believe that major VPN providers' Mac app has this function, and if you toggle this function, you can get your problem solved.

ps.: I strictly use Wireguard protocol, not OpenVPN. Not sure if it has anything to do with it, just saying...

Comment: The question here is specifically about Sidecar (otherwise it would be a duplicate of the question you've already answered before).